# Update Modified By Field with SharePoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working with a developer who has managed to add and update list items via the REST API on our SharePoint site.  He would like to programmatically change the Modified By field.  He has added this field in the REST XML

```
<d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">6545</d:ModifiedById>
```

However, the list item continues to show the service account that is running the REST API instead of the user specified by the ModifiedById field.  I've searched all over and cannot find a reference to using the REST API to change these values.  My developer has tried using d:Editor but that throws an error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Response: Error processing request stream. 
The property name 'Editor' specified for type
'Microsoft.SharePoint.DataService.DocumentsItem' is not valid.
```

What, if any, is the way to make this change?

Comment: What are you passing as Editor? The actual username? Does it have permissions on the List?

Comment: We're sending the userid. The account has contribute rights

Comment: You mention: "My developer has tried using d:Editor but that throws an error", what were you passing as the Editor value? Also if you submit other values do they persist ok? Just ruling out problems with the call

Comment: When using editor, he's using the same ID. The issue with editor is that the field doesn't exist as per the error message

Comment: When submitting other bakues, % the changes are saved

Comment: I am affraid it cannot be done then, unless someone else has any ideas, with these kind of issues usually I roll my own web api. You can even do one with a sandbox solution, I know it is convuluted and hard but it pays off on flexibility this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billgr/archive/2011/01/31/sandboxed-web-request-handler.aspx , some reflection and Javascript Serialiser and you got yourself a home baked web api in sharepoint with total control on what you need to do